# train test split in python but consider patient information?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do train test splitting (mainly interested in crossvalidation) in python such that I don't end up with data points from the same patient in both train and test? That is, I'd like to first split the patients into train and test then the observations accordingly.

Is there a functionality for this kind of scenario or do I have to code it manually?

Answer (score 0):

[Sklearn GroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold) should solve this task. K-fold iterator variant with **non-overlapping groups**. The same group will not appear in two different folds:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
groups = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2])
group_kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)

group_kfold.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)
```